# Adding Values to a List and Converting to BigInteger - Java

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, linked-list, biginteger

I'm writing a code that determines the smallest integer that is a sequence of sevens followed by some number of zeros (possibly none) that is divisible by `int n`. Since this number can be massive, the return value should be a `BigInteger`.

My code so far has an if-else ladder that covers the case that if any `int n` is not divisible by two or five is guaranteed to only contain sevens (no zeros). In the case where `int n` is not divisible by two or five, my thought process was to continue adding sevens to a LinkedList in a while loop, until that list (converted to a BigInteger) is divisible by `int n`. The same logic goes for the case where `int n` is divisible by two or five, except a two for-loops would add seven and zero to the list.

My code is getting a runtime error when converting the list to  a string and then to a `BigInteger`, specifically on the line `BigInteger numBig = new BigInteger(str);`. The error is: "java.lang.NumberFormatException: Zero length BigInteger (in java.math.BigInteger)" Also, I'm not quite sure the logic is sound for the case where `int n` is divisible by two or five.

Comment: Do you know how to debug a java program? You are sending and empty list as an argument to method `convert()`.

Comment: I just realized that from the last comment that was written. I'll have to rework it. Hoping to get an answer still on the logic though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need BigInteger for this task. The idea is the following:

- First you determine the number of required zeros. Since number composed of only sevens cannot be divided by 2 or 5, the number of zeros is equal to the maximum power of 2 or 5 in number `n`.
- Now we have a number `n` which is not divisible by 2 or 5. Suppose that a remainder of the division of a number composed of `m` sevens by `n` is equal to `r`:

```
777...m-times..777 mod n = r
```

Then number composed of (m+1) sevens will have a remainder 10*r + 7, because

```
777..(m+1)-times...777 = 777...m-times...7 * 10 + 7
```

So you can just recalculate the remainder until it becomes zero.

```
public static BigInteger method(int n) {
    int two;
    for (two = 0; n % 2 == 0; two++) n /= 2;
    int five;
    for (five = 0; n % 5 == 0; five++) n /= 5;
    int zeros = Math.max(two, five);
    int sevens = 1;
    int r = 7 % n;
    while (r != 0) {
      r = (r * 10 + 7) % n;
      sevens++;
    }
    // Now just make a number of 'sevens' sevens and 'zeros' zeros:
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < sevens; i++) {
      result.append("7");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < zeros; i++) {
      result.append("0");
    }
    return new BigInteger(result.toString());
  }
```

Comment: it has to return BigInteger or the tester doesn't work

Comment: @NikeDog Well, then just change the last statement to `return new BigInteger(result.toString());`

Answer (score 0):

"Zero length BigInteger" means you're trying to create a BigInteger from something that has length of 0. The stack trace would tell you on which line exactly.

I would guess the bug is in your `convert` method. If you pass in an empty list, it tries to convert an empty string into BigInteger with `new BigInteger("")`

I don't know what your algorithm is supposed to do in this case. If for example you want to convert an empty list into the number zero, you can do:

```
if (res.isEmpty()) return BigInteger.ZERO;
```